# std::vector and memory allocation

Tags: c++, stdvector

It seems that every time you append a new element to a `std::vector`, if there aren't empty elements, the number of allocated elements is doubled (at least in GCC 4.9). I think this is done in order to achieve amortized constant time complexity.

E.g., after running this code:

```
v.push_back (1);
v.push_back (2);
v.push_back (3);
v.push_back (4);
v.push_back (5);

v.shrink_to_fit(); // capacity is 5 now
v.push_back (6);

std::cout << v.capacity () << std::endl;
```

The output is 10.

In memory constrained systems, is there any way to prevent this behaviour even if it is at the cost of a performance penalty?

Moreover, would it be possible to indicate that it should allocate only a fixed number of elements instead of doubling it?

I know I can call `std::vector::reserve()` before adding new elements, but it seems a mess in my case... calling `std::vector::shrink_to_fit()` is another approach, but also inconvenient.

Comment: Did you actually check the capacity after the call to `shrink_to_fit`?

Comment: To avoid (reduce) the mess, you could write your own free function that takes a vector and an element to add and then does `v.reserve(v.size() + 1)` followed by a `push_back`.

Comment: why not use array in that case (if you need fixed size)

Comment: @0d0a I think jbgs wants a fixed growth rate, not a fixed size.

Comment: According to the standard adding and element to the vector need to be amortized constant time, this is only get, using a `factor > 1` to increase the size of the vector the values more common are `1.5` and `2`. But don't think that `std::vector` would let you change this (eg: increasing 5 element when growing) because would contradict the standard complexity time.

Comment: @dlf, `fixed number of elements`, i understand increasing every time in N element (where N have some constant value in the execution). You could use `std::list`.

Comment: The answer to your question is very simple. No and no. You already know the workaround to your problem, but are unwilling to use it, so I won't bother explaining it.

Comment: `std::vector` does amortize memory allocation across element adds.  Like @NetVipeC mentioned, the size increase factors are typically 1.5 or 2 (gcc).  Without that, you have linear complexity element adds due to copies.  Technically, you need to consider the complexity of the heap allocation as well.  Maybe you need a different data structure?

Comment: You could you boost::static_vector http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.static_vector

Comment: @dif: [`v.reserve(v.size() + 1)` will result in `v.capacity()` being *at least* `v.size() + 1`, not *exactly*](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/074.htm) (which is what it seems like the OP is wanting.

Comment: @juanchopanza: yes, capacity after calling `shrink_to_fit` is 5.

Comment: @dlf Cornstalks is right http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve

Comment: @0d0a Yup. Redacted (but I'll leave my incorrect comment to avoid making nonsense out of the rest of them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no way.

Your only option is to write your own vector data structure and that way you can do whatever you want with it (or you could just copy an implementation of the internet/c++ library and change what you need and include that new vector in your program).

Actually you can also use an array and the `realloc` command.

Comment: How do you use an array together with realloc?